# Replace Image In Grid View

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, imageview, drawable

I am using a grid view to display some image links using async task.
I want to setup an empty image view in the grid view first and then replace a particular image view with the image download from internet.
Any idea how I can replace the image?

Comment: Post what you have done, then it will be easy for others to help you. No one will write the code from beginning here. You should ask questions when you are facing problems after trying.

Comment: Try the Picasso library. It supports both download and error placeholders - http://square.github.io/picasso/ Images will be replaced accordingly once the download is complete.

Comment: Question might say "Any idea"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting those urls you have to download those images after that set those images in `GridView`.

Take a look at this tutorial

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Or you can use [LazyLoading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) or you can use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginner Please read this tutorial loading images using LazyLoading 
Please see this [tutorial link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

You can also use Google Volley Libray also.

Sample tutorial how to use volley in your app [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)